# Invalid file identifier in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to read a text file using `textscan(fID,format)`. However, I get an error telling me `Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier`. I used `fopen` to generate  fID and got -1. I don't remember having ever seen an identifier to -1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) cannot open the file, then `fID` is -1.

Possible Causes :

- Wrong File Path.
- Corrupt File.
- File doesn't exist
- File already in use.