# What could be wrong with the file path in the following code?

Tags: matlab

I understand that this could be due to a wrong file path but I have tried all the ways to correct it and still ending up with the same error. The code is given below.

```
clc
clear all
fid=fopen('ECresult.txt','w');
for p=1:2;
% textFilename{p} = fullfile('/ccc/Desktop/Lalitha-18/EO',['EO' num2str(p)'.txt']);
textFilename{p} = fullfile('C:/Users/Biswajit/Desktop/Biswajit_nimmy',['LC1EC1' num2str(p) '.txt']);

id{p} = fopen(textFilename{p},'rt'); 
textdata{p} = textscan(id{p},'%s%s'); 
fclose(id{p});

p
X=load(['EC' num2str(p) '.txt']);
N=length(X)
m=2;
counter1=0; counter2=0;
k=0.2;
r = k*std(X);
i=1;j=1;
while i<= N-m
Y=[X(i:i+m-1)];
while j<=N-m
    Z=[X(j:j+m-1)];
    d1=abs(Y-Z);
    if d1<=r
    counter1=counter1 + 1;
    end
    j=j+1;
  end
  IC(i) = counter1/(N-m);
 counter1=0;j=1;
 i=i+1;
end
i=1;
m=m+1;
while i <= N-m
 Y = [X(i:i+m-1)];
 while j<= (N-m)
    Z = [X(j:j+m-1)];
    d2 = abs(Y-Z);
    if d2<=r
    counter2=counter2 +1;
    end
   j=j+1;
  end
 ID(i)=counter2/(N-m);
 counter2=0; j=1;
 i = i+1;
 end
 Entropy=0;
 i=1;
 while i<=N-m
 Ratio=IC(i)/ID(i);
 Entropy=Entropy +log (Ratio);
 i = i+1;
 end
 Approxntropy(p) = Entropy/(N-m); 
fid=fopen('EO.txt','w');
fprintf(fid, '%5.6f\r\n', Approxntropy);
end
```

The exact error message is as below

"
   Error using textscan
  Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in Apensdploop (line 13)
    textdata{p} = textscan(id{p},'%s%s');
"
Please advise.

Comment: Have a look at the following questions: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20805070/3599179) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10606373/3599179).

Answer (score 0):

Your error message means that fopen was unable to open the file. In this case, it returns -1. Since you didn't catch the error, you passed -1 to `textscan` which then complains. Therefore, before passing `id{p}` to `textscan`, you should check if it is -1, which means an error.

What you are passing to fopen is

`fullfile('C:/Users/Biswajit/Desktop/Biswajit_nimmy',['LC1EC1' num2str(p) '.txt']);`

which for `p = 1` becomes

`'C:/Users/Biswajit/Desktop/Biswajit_nimmyLC1EC11.txt'`

Looks like a slash is missing to me. Try

`fullfile('C:/Users/Biswajit/Desktop/Biswajit_nimmy/',['LC1EC1' num2str(p) '.txt']);`

instead?

Otherwise, set a breakpoint at the `fopen` like and look at the content of `textFilename{p}`. Then you will see if it contains the correct path and file name or not.

Comment: I have incorporated that slash that you had mentioned and then set a breakpoint on the line "id{p} = fopen(textFilename{p},'rt'); " and checked that textFilename contains the following path "C:\Users\Biswajit\Desktop\Biswajit_nimmy\LC1EC11.txt". But the error stays.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in this folder and has exactly this name? Try `dir(textFilename{p})`, does it show up? If not, try `dir("C:\Users\Biswajit\Desktop\Biswajit_nimmy\*.txt")`. If it does, there must be another reason why fopen cannot open it. Is it maybe locked by another program?

Comment: One thing that I forgot to mention earlier is that fid is NOT -1 when I run the code. This indicates that the file can be opened. fid comes out to be 5 or 8 or 16 and so on.

Comment: Florian, I tried using dir(textFilename{p}) and it shows that "C:\Users\Biswajit\Desktop\Biswajit_nimmy\LC1EC11.txt' not found".  I don't know from where the extra '1' has cropped up. This is why it hasn't been able to locate the file, I believe. This is what was also there in the textFilename cell earlier when checked with the breakpoint. How can that be possible?

Comment: What's the correct filename? LC1EC1.txt? Or LCEC11.txt? How about the second one (p=2)?

Comment: There are two text files. For p=1, LC1EC1.txt  and for (p=2) LC2EC2.txt.

Comment: Then your assignment to `textFilename{p}` should be `['LC1EC' num2str(p) '.txt']` instead of `['LC1EC1' num2str(p) '.txt']`.